# Redis/Node update blocked by all firewalls

Tags: node.js, ssl, redis, firewall

I recently updated from Redis 5.04 to 7.0.11 in my program, and it works fine across public networks, but for some reason it's being blocked by all firewalls.

Is there a reason for this specific behavior, and is there something I need to do to fix it?

This is the only thing I changed/added in my code, to allow for TLS connections.

```
const redisURL = configService.get(ENV_REDIS_URL)
const redisOptions = {
    url: redisURL,
    ...(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' && { tls: { rejectUnauthorized: false } })
}

export const redisClient = redis.createClient(redisOptions)
export const subscribeClient = redisClient.duplicate()
```